# CSS Less changes not showing. Compile or IIS error?

Tags: html, css, iis, compilation, less

I have changed my `LESS` CSS code directly on the file which is hosted on a server.

But anything I change in this file, -which I thought was being loaded on every page request, do not appear visually whenever the page using the styling is loaded.

Now, I understand that `LESS` is somehow compiled into "raw" `CSS` in some way, but I do not know exactly how. I imagine this not happening might be the error.

Another idea that I had was about the `IIS`, which is pointing to the site. Is it possible that the `IIS` needs to be refreshed in any way to make the LESS code recompile?

I believe that if I just get the `LESS` code to recompile itself, it would work fine. What could be preventing me from doing just that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile .scss files (SASS). 
If you are using Visual Studio, you need to install Web Essentials 2013.5 extension ([link](http://vswebessentials.com/)).

If not using VS, there are many good compilers for SASS files including KOALA ([link](http://koala-app.com/)).

Comment: Thank you. Now I know that my style.css file is the compiled version of my syle.less file. But it still is not taking any Visual effect on my site.
There must be something that needs to be refreshed, such as the IIS

Comment: Refresh on IIS site solved the delayed effect. Setting your answer as Solved. Have a good weekend!

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help.